# Trigger an application using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll

Tags: .net, c++-cli, delay, taskscheduler

I'm working on VS2015. I want to trigger to run my application after 20 seconds. How can i do it with Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll? 
My code is as below:

```
    void Actions::ScheduleRunApp()
{
    TaskService^ ts = gcnew TaskService();
    TaskDefinition^ td = ts->NewTask();
    td->RegistrationInfo->Description = "Run LocalLockApp";
    //td->Triggers->Add(gcnew DailyTrigger(2)); i want to run the application after 20 seconds instead
    td->Actions->Add(gcnew ExecAction("notepad.exe", "C:\\test.log", nullptr));
    ts->RootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(L"Test",td);
    ts->RootFolder->DeleteTask(L"Test",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two applications, and you're trying to have application #1 run application #2, probably having application #1 exit before application #2 is started.

At first glance, I would say that using Task Scheduler for this is the wrong solution. Task Scheduler is for launching maintenance tasks on a regular basis, such as every day at 4:00 am. You could create a task that is triggered to run only once, at now + 20 seconds, but there's probably better ways of doing this.

In this case, I would do one of two things:

- Keep application #1 running. Sleep for 20 seconds, and then run application #2. Hide your window if the user has requested application exit.
- Create a helper application. The job of this helper application is to delay 20 seconds and then run application #2. Have application #1 launch the helper application, then application #1 is free to exit. You could even do this with a batch file if you don't want to have another .exe file hanging around.

If you absolutely must use Task Scheduler, then I believe you want [`TimeTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/timetrigger) instead of `DailyTrigger`. You also probably don't want to call DeleteTask before it has run: Instead, make sure the properties are set so that the task auto-deletes when it's not scheduled to run any more.

Comment: `DateTime^ scheduledTime = gcnew DateTime(nowTime->Year, nowTime->Month, nowTime->Day, 8, 59, 0);
td->Triggers->Add(gcnew TimeTrigger(scheduledTime));` 

I code like above. But it is said: TimeTRigger doesn't match the argument `scheduledTime`. But i see `TimeTrigger(System::DateTime startBoundary)` ? What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `DateTime` is a struct, not a class (value type, not reference type). Don't use `^`, don't use `gcnew`. And if your goal is to run it 20 seconds from now, better would be `DateTime::Now + TimeSpan::FromSeconds(20)`

Comment: `void Actions::ScheduleRunApp()
 {
  TaskService^ ts = gcnew TaskService();
  TaskDefinition^ td = ts->NewTask();
  td->RegistrationInfo->Description = "Run LocalLockApp";
  td->Triggers->Add(gcnew TimeTrigger(DateTime::Now + TimeSpan::FromSeconds(5)));
  td->Actions->Add(gcnew ExecAction("notepad.exe", "file.txt", nullptr));
  ts->RootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td);
  ts->RootFolder->DeleteTask("Test", true);
 }`
It still hasn't worked. I don't know where i am wrong

Comment: `ts->RootFolder->DeleteTask("Test", true);` Well, you are deleting the task before it gets a chance to run...

Comment: My code works well on win 7. But it doesn't work on win 10. Do you think if version of window affect TaskScheduler ?